# contextualMenu item onSelected show another menu

Tags: smartface.io

is it possible to show another menu on select of optionalMenu item, app stopping running if i click item on first menu.

```
function rightMenuF() {

 var item1 = {
    title : lang["lng_logout"],
    //icon : "Icon.png", // Android 3.0 only
    //itemType : SMF.UI.MenuItemType.cancel, //  iOS Optional Menu only
    onSelected : function (e) {
        openNewMenu();
    }
};
var items = [item1];
Menus.RightOptionalMenu = new SMF.UI.Menu({
    menuStyle : SMF.UI.MenuStyle.optionalMenu, 
        title : lang["lng_settings"],
        //icon : "Icon.png",
        items : items
    });
Menus.RightOptionalMenu.show();
}

function openNewMenu() {

 var item1 = {
    title : lang["lng_logout"],
    //icon : "Icon.png", // Android 3.0 only
    //itemType : SMF.UI.MenuItemType.cancel, //  iOS Optional Menu only
    onSelected : function (e) {
        alert("a");
    }
};
var items = [item1];
Menus.NewOptionalMenu = new SMF.UI.Menu({
    menuStyle : SMF.UI.MenuStyle.optionalMenu, 
        title : lang["lng_settings"], 
        //icon : "Icon.png", 
        items : items
    });
Menus.NewOptionalMenu .show();
}
```

rightMenuF triggering by actionBar item.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but there are some JavaScript problems in your codeLines.

Firstly, you can use Menu.JS in the project as a guide , also there is an article about Menu Object at http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/menu-object/  .

Now, create a new project.

Open Global.JS File and uncomment the codeLine below;

```
 load("Menu.js");
```

Now, Open Menu.JS File and change the code like below;

```
var item1 = {
    title : "My Item 1",
    icon : "icon.png", // Andrid 3.0- only
    itemType : SMF.UI.MenuItemType.destructive, //  iOS Optional Menu Only
    onSelected : function (e) {
        Menus.newMenu2.show();

        alert("First item is selected");
    }
};

var item2 = {
    title : "My Item 2",
    itemType : SMF.UI.MenuItemType.destructive, //  iOS Optional Menu Only
    onSelected : function (e) {
        alert("Second item is selected");
    }
};

var items = [item1, item2];

Menus.newMenu = new SMF.UI.Menu({
        menuStyle : SMF.UI.MenuStyle.contextualMenu,
        title : "Menu Title", // iOS Optional Menu Only
        icon : "menu_icon.png", // Android Context Menu Only
        items : items
    });

Menus.newMenu2 = new SMF.UI.Menu({
        menuStyle : SMF.UI.MenuStyle.optionalMenu,
        title : "Menu Title", // iOS Optional Menu Only
        icon : "menu_icon.png", // Android Context Menu Only
        items : items
    });

//    Use following commands to show menus
/*
Menus.newMenu.show();
Menus.newMenu2.show();
*/
```

Now create a button for example and write the code below on its onPressed event;

```
Menus.newMenu.show();
```

When you run the project, if you pressed the button it will show you the first menu. and if you touch the first item it will show you the second menu.